# Why does git merge create a commit in source branch

Tags: git, github, merge

I'm trying to merge changes from a patch branch into main. This is the message I see in github:

```
kewp wants to merge 36 commits into patch/SEO_prices_pages from development
```

When I click to resolve conflicts this is the message I see

```
Resolving conflicts between development and patch/SEO_prices_pages and committing changes development
```

Why is the commit being committed into `development` ? I am trying to update the patch branch with the development changes...

Comment: If you're merging two branches the new commit is a parent of both branches

Comment: I don't see why that needs to be the case. Surely I just change my target branch to have the needed changes?

Comment: You can, but that's not a merge. Sounds like you want a cherry-pick or rebase.

Comment: Hmmm I see thanks I'll look that up.

Comment: @symlink That's incorrect. If you merge, for example, a branch into master the branch remains the same.

Comment: "*I'm trying to merge changes from a patch branch into main.*" Instead of "main" do you mean "development"? If so, it seems you're doing the opposite. You're merging *into* the patch branch *from* development. Can you show us `git log --graph --decorate` for both patch/SEO_prices_pages and development? And can you show us what specific commands or tools you're using?

Comment: @symlink is not quite correct, but I'm not sure what is meant by a "parent of both branches".  The new commit is a commit in each branch.  If it has any descendants, those commits may or may not be a commit in the branches.

Comment: @symlink The new commit is a *child* of the *commits* being merged.

@Schwern You can use `git log --graph --oneline --all`, `--decorate` is on by default since git 2.13.

@WilliamPursell "The new commit is a commit in each branch." The new commit is a commit in the *current* branch (the branch being merged into).

Comment: @krisz right, substitute child for parent.

Comment: Hi @Schwern as mentioned below I am using Github for tooling

Comment: Not sure how to post the `git log` it's quite long?

Comment: I have done so, thanks @matt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a basic flaw in the question:

> Why does git merge create a commit in source branch

It doesn't.  Git*Hub*, on the other hand ...

It's important to define terms here, and to distinguish very clearly between what *Git* does, and what *GitHub* does.  GitHub is not Git!  GitHub will *host* a Git repository *for* you, and then they add on their own features, to get you to use their service (instead of some competitor's).  So when you use GitHub's add-ons, they may well do things that Git itself does not do.  (If you *like* those things, GitHub are succeeding: remember, their goal is to get you to use them, and ultimately, to get you or someone else to pay them.)

#### The setup

> [GitHub tells me] `kewp wants to merge 36 commits into patch/SEO_prices_pages from development` [but there are merge conflicts]

I'll assume here that `kewp` is *you* and that `development` is the name you gave GitHub when you sent some commits from your laptop/desktop/whatever computer, to the repository over on GitHub.  Then you used GitHub's web interface to generate a GitHub Pull Request (PR), using your `development` as the merge-from branch and `patch/SEO_price_pages` as the merge-to branch, all within a single repository over on GitHub (so that no extra GitHub fork stuff is involved here).

A GitHub PR is not a Git merge.  What GitHub do when you click on the "make PR" buttons does, however, involve *attempting* a `git merge` in a Git repository stored on GitHub.  This attempt may either succeed or fail.  If it succeeds, the resulting *merge commit* can be found in the Git on GitHub; if not, there is no such merge commit.

A GitHub PR is assigned a number, unique to that repository on GitHub.  (It's a number that is global across all operations within that repository: issues and PRs share the number space, so in a repository with no activity yet, if you create a few dozen issues before creating any PRs, the first PR will have a two-digit number.)  This number becomes a Git *namespace* of the form `refs/pull/number`.  Within this namespace, GitHub create either one name, or two:

- `refs/pull/number/head` refers to the *tip commit* of the branch you asked to merge *from*; and
- `refs/pull/number/merge`, if it exists, refers to the *merge commit* that GitHub successfully made.

This merge commit is not (yet) on *any* branch.  If it exists, it exists in the Git repository over at GitHub, and is findable under the `merge` name, but the phrase *commit C is on branch B* in Git is generally interpreted to mean that commit C is *reachable from* the tip commit of branch *B*.

(For much more on reachability, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).)

Again, if the merge attempt fails, there is no merge commit here.  Since there *were* merge conflicts in your case, there is a `refs/pull/number/head` name, but there is no `refs/pull/number/merge` name.

#### How merge works on your laptop

When you use Git on your laptop, you might perform a merge like this:

```
git checkout patch/SEO_prices_pages
git merge development
```

If there are conflicts, your Git will *stop in the middle of the merge*, with the results of the partially-completed merge left in both Git's index and your work-tree.  You can now *resolve* these conflicts, using the stuff Git left behind in its index and your work-tree, any way you like.  You then tell Git that you have resolved the conflicts, and use:

```
git merge --continue
```

to resume (and finish this time) the merge.  The result is a new commit.  The new commit is on—and at the tip of—the branch you had checked out, i.e., `patch/SEO_prices_pages`.  The branch you named in your `git merge` command, i.e., `development`, is entirely unchanged: that name still holds the same commit hash it held before you started all of this.

The merge resolution process occurred in Git's index, but your assist almost certainly used your files in your work-tree: your computer's non-Git commands *can't* use the files that are in Git's index, as they're in a special, compressed, Git-only format.  To use an index file, you have to copy it out somewhere (typically with `git checkout` or `git checkout-index`), then work on it there, then copy it back over the old index file (typically with `git add`).

The final commit has two parents: its first parent is the commit that *was* the tip of `patch/SEO_prices_pages` a moment ago, and its second parent is the commit that still *is* the tip of `development`.

#### How conflict resolution works on GitHub

The Git repositories on GitHub have no work-tree.  (Each one does have an index, but it's mostly just vestigial.)  This means that the usual tools are just not available.

What GitHub offer, at least today, is a sort of a trick.  They save some of the conflict information somewhere—there's only one index and there might be multiple PRs "in flight", so it's not at all clear *where*, although Git does have the ability to use an alternative index, so perhaps there's an index per PR, though I would guess not—but since there is no work-tree, there is no place to just edit a file and then `git add` it again.

Instead, what GitHub do when you use their conflict resolution tool is *make more commits*.  They *could* make these commits by advancing the `refs/pull/number/head` ref, and I think eventually they *do* advance it, but according to [their own information page](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/resolving-a-merge-conflict-on-github), they add the new commit—which uses your PR branch's tip commit's files as a starting point, but makes changes that will result in the `git merge` *not* having a conflict—to *your branch*.

In this case, what this means is that they:

- extract the files from the commit at the tip of your on-GitHub-repo's `development`;
- allow you to make changes to each of the files that have conflicts, such that if this were made as a new commit on your `development`, those files would no longer have merge conflicts with the files in the tip commit of `patch/SEO_prices_pages`;
- allow you to add *this* commit to your on-GitHub-repo.

This is the equivalent of you, on your laptop, doing:

```
git checkout development
```

(Note: this assumes your `development` matches your GitHub's `development`!) and then:

```
<edit each file that had conflicts>
<git add each such file>
git commit
git push origin development
```

except of course that by doing this directly with your GitHub repo, you don't get the commit on your laptop (yet).

Now that your GitHub repo `development` has this *new* commit, GitHub can try the `git merge` again.  This time the merge will succeed and they will be able to create `refs/pull/number/merge`.

#### More notes about GitHub oddities

When you actually are allowed to merge on GitHub, you will see that the green "merge" button has a dropdown arrow.  Using the dropdown, you'll see that there are three options:

- merge
- rebase and merge
- squash and merge

The first one does just what it says.  It uses a normal everyday merge—the one GitHub already made will do just fine—and tacks that on to the target branch as usual.

The second one *copies* each of the to-be-merged commits to new commits that extend the target branch.  GitHub do this even if the to-be-merge commits are already in the right position, graph-wise, to have been fast-forwarded.  (I find this obnoxious myself: they should just fast-forward.)

The last one does the equivalent of running `git checkout <target>; git merge --squash ...`.  It probably uses the tree from the existing merge, by running `git commit-tree` on GitHub, but the effect is the same.

Comment: What a detailed answer, thank you. It's going to take me a while to absorb it. Will come back